Maui SplashScreen в темной теме затемнение
Ошибка заключается в том что в темной теме вокруг лого затемнение.
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#57B8FF" Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) != 'ios'" />

Темная тема
Темная тема
Светлая темаСветлая тема
Как можно исправить данную проблему? Так же пробовал делать свою тему и задавать цвет но результат такой же
SVG картинка 
<svg width="451" height="251" viewBox="0 0 451 251" fill="57B8FF" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M258.526 0.762695C316.272 0.762695 364.473 41.4105 376.165 95.9264C417.207 98.0784 449.898 132.27 450.137 174.114C450.137 217.153 414.821 250.388 371.631 250.388H350.872H84.8119C81.2326 250.388 77.8323 250.328 74.432 250.269C71.0317 250.209 67.6313 250.149 64.0521 250.149C28.2593 250.149 0.102295 223.608 0.102295 187.743C0.102295 155.224 23.9641 128.206 54.9846 123.423C53.5528 117.685 52.837 111.707 52.837 105.73C52.837 66.7556 84.3346 34.9547 123.468 34.9547C138.262 34.9547 152.102 39.4977 163.556 47.3881C185.509 19.1738 219.87 0.762695 258.526 0.762695ZM298.375 54.5613H271.889V69.6249L298.375 91.3834V54.5613ZM410.526 207.11C410.526 221.456 401.936 233.89 389.528 239.389C403.606 234.846 413.867 221.456 413.867 205.676C413.867 186.308 398.118 170.527 378.79 170.527H375.449V168.375C375.449 144.704 356.121 125.815 332.736 125.815C328.919 125.815 325.339 126.293 321.999 127.249L324.385 124.141L228.937 43.5625L133.49 124.141L142.796 136.335L228.937 64.3646L310.545 132.27C306.011 135.379 301.955 138.965 298.614 143.508V134.901L228.46 75.8416L159.499 134.901V219.783H213.666C214.382 225.282 217.245 230.303 221.063 234.129C217.245 228.869 214.859 222.413 214.859 215.479C214.859 198.024 228.937 185.352 246.118 182.482C246.661 182.392 247.409 182.335 248.221 182.274C249.549 182.175 251.046 182.062 252.083 181.765C252.322 167.658 262.583 158.572 276.661 158.572C281.195 158.572 287.638 161.68 291.933 164.789C299.091 144.465 310.545 128.923 331.543 128.923C354.928 128.923 374.017 148.051 374.495 171.962C374.614 171.962 374.674 172.022 374.733 172.081C374.793 172.141 374.853 172.201 374.972 172.201C394.3 172.201 410.526 187.743 410.526 207.11ZM251.129 178.896V139.444H208.655V187.265H225.358C228.745 183.192 237.474 179.762 239.413 179C239.523 178.957 239.611 178.922 239.675 178.896C245.402 177.223 251.129 178.896 251.129 178.896Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>


Положить на фон не цвет, а картинку сплошного цвета например, как обои. Типа 8x8 PNG подойдёт.

К сожалению такого свойства нет в MauiSplashScreen, фон можно задать через Color только

Покажите код SVG картинки. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Добавил картинку и код картинки

Проверил на пустом проекте данная проблема возникает если менять сам фон в MauiSplashScreen

fill="57B8FF" уберите из svg и посмотрите, что будет

изменил на fill="none", изменений не каких

Причем хочу заметить что данная проблема проявляется только на устройствах xiaomi HyperOS, проверял на эмуляторе, там отображается как надо без затемнения

Меня даже устроит вариант если затемнение будет но полноценное без за светлённого квадрата, так же fill="#00000000" - результат не дал

Магии не бывает, у вас вероятно кеширована картинка. Переустановите отлаживаемое приложение и т.д. fill достаточно надо просто убрать. Пока выглядит что эффекта нет из-за того что картинка старая.

Исправил, но затемнение не ушло как предполагаю это уже сама MIUI затемняет.
Создал в ресурсах drawable внутри папки splash_screen.xml - AndroidResource.
splash_screen.xml
<item
    android:width="384dp"
    android:height="384dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/Cloud"
        android:gravity="fill" />
</item>

Далее добавил папки values и values-night в них colors.xml и styles.xml
В styles.xml
<!-- Splash theme -->
  <style name="Maui.SplashTheme" parent="Maui.MainTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="maui_splash">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <!--
          Android 12+ specific settings
          See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen#set-theme
        -->
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/maui_splash_color_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/cloudanimatedicon</item>
  </style>

